# Too much time on a request making calls to https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track

Tags: performance, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, dynatrace

I have an Application stored on azure.
When i analyze the time spent on a simple request, i found more than 30 secons on a total of 32 in calls to https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track.
I know these are telemetry calls, but why so much time on that?

[image: Dynatrace request details]